# Redirecting user to the new URL

Tags: python, django

There is a url:

```
/foo
```

I would like everything to get redirected like this:

```
/foo/xxx --> /bar/xxx
/foo/xxx/yyy --> /bar/xxx/yyy
```

How does Django url-pattern has too look like to redirect all *foo* to *bar*?

Something like this?

```
url(r'^foo/????$', RedirectView.as_view())
```

This is what I was using for "zero-level" redirects and it works:

```
url(r'^foo/?$', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='template_name'))
```

Comment: Have you tried any pattern? Show it!

Comment: `url(r'^foo/(.*)', lambda request, path: redirect('/bar/' + path))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the rest part of the path in the url pattern.

And pass the path combined with `/bar/` to [`redirect` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect):

```
url(r'^foo/(.*)', lambda request, path: redirect('/bar/' + path))
```

Comment: Great idea! And it worked very well. But what if I have information before /bar? For example /baz/foo/xxx becomes /bar/xxx. How do I make sure /baz/ is not lost?

Comment: @h3d0, You can add another pattern: `(.*?)/foo/(.*)` with slightly modified `lambda`. Now, you need to think about the url: `/foo/baz/foo/foo/` ...

Comment: Well, thanks for help - now I know where to look at!

Comment: Final solution looked like: url(r'^foo/(.*)', lambda request, path: redirect(request.get_absolute_url() + 'bar/' + path)), where get_absolute_url was getting what I was needed (user's domain name).